# Onerror event add a new class and count how many times it replaces image source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `onerror` feature to detect broken links and replace those with an image, the problem is that in my code images that are okay are clickable.

So I want to make it in that way that when the function `imageOnError` is called to make that image impossible to click. 
I tried to do it like this `(img).unbind("click");` 
Lik this also: `img.class = "blocked";`

but it doesn't work?

```
<img  class="img img-click not-selected " src="" onerror="return imageOnError(this);" />

countImgReplaced = 0;
function imageOnError(img) {
    img.onerror = '';
    img.src = 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256?text=Broken%20images%20.';
    (img).unbind("click");
     countImgReplaced ++;
    return true;
}
```

And also I want to get the number of times that the image is replaced I did that with `countImgReplaced` , but it gives me the total number of images :/

I'm really confused. Can somebody help me?

Comment: A class is added by `className` property, not `class`. Also, the passed `img` is a DOM element, you need a jQuery object to utilize jQuery methods (`unbind`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `pointer-events: none;` to them via a class. You can apply that using the classList API

i.e.

```
img.classList.add('blocked');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this in HTML tag.

```
<img  src="../resources/images/Image1.jpg" onerror="this.src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';this.style='pointer-events: none'" />
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
     alert("Valid");
  });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="clear:both;"><lable>Click in image(Invalid img):</lable>

<img width=200px height=200px src="../resources/images/Image1.jpg" onerror="this.src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';this.style='pointer-events: none'" />
</div>

<div style="clear:both;"><lable>Click in image (Valid img):<lable>
<img width=200px height=200px src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQzltPjpuUfCzEsYbhTYTm4xab4wfmCTFoNllbU5ljLLEAb3VvJXkgpWvU" onerror="this.src='https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';this.style='pointer-events: none'" /></div>
```